# after run python script to run recursive rename my files has disappeared

Tags: python

I've just run this script to rename my files, adding the 15 first chars of files, but now all the files are disappearead, and i can't find them. i've just run this on a mac

```
import os
def replace(folder_path, old, new):
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for name in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(path,name)
            new_name = os.path.basename(path)[:15] + " - " + name
            print path  + "##" + new_name
            os.rename(file_path, new_name)

replace('/Users/myuser/mp3/', '', '')
```

Comment: The `print` should have told you where they went...

Comment: the print show me the original path and name , but i've just found the on the path where i've executed  this file; why the file are moved and not renamed ?

Comment: There is no difference between a move and a rename. They are moved to a different name.

Comment: ah ok, so i had to add the path to the name, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DDave,

In the function call os.rename(src, dst): **src** is the fully qualified filepath of the source file, and **dst** is fully qualified filepath of the target file.

In your above program, new_name is just the new name of the file which does not have the directory information (and hence it is considering the directory as your current working directory). That is why you are not seeing the renamed files where you were looking to see them.

The program is rather trying to create the files under your current working directory. Run the following from your console of your IDE or from your program to figure out the current working directory:

```
print(os.getcwd())
```

Providing the full solution as requested in the comment below:

```
import os
def replace(folder_path, old, new):
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for name in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(path,name)
            # new_name = os.path.basename(path)[:15] + " - " + name
            new_filepath = os.path.join(path, (name[:15] if len(name)>=15 else name) + " - " + name)
            print ("new path: " + new_filepath)
            os.rename(file_path, new_filepath)
```

Comment: thanks , that's ive unserstood, but can you fix the line on my code to add the path?

Comment: @DDave provided the full solution now. Please work on the naming the files as per your required logic. But wanted to give you the main basic idea where you needed to change, which is while building the new file path: new_filepath = os.path.join(path, (name[:15] if len(name)>=15 else name) + " - " + name)   . Added a failsafe condition as well to tackle the scenario of files whose filename is < 15 char long. This above code is tested in Windows.